# Why is the Kaaba covered in black cloth?

Tags: kaabah

I found [this](http://www.questionsonislam.com/question/why-covering-kaaba-black) online, explaining in part why the Kaaba is covered in black cloth, that it is a sign of respect. But I still don't fully understand why covering it in black cloth is respectful. Could someone help explain this for me please?

Comment: I don't see in the reference that it is covered in black for respect. Also it was covered in different colors previously (Green, white, red, ...).

Comment: I realised that . Respect is not in the color. Its in our mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not serve any religious reasons as far as I know, and is basically an act of respect dating to before the Prophet's time. Even the polytheists of Makkah regarded the Ka'aba with great respect, and took great pride in beautifying it. This included draping it with fine cloth, and at one time adorning it with copies of the day's greatest poems (known as Al Mu'alaqat). And it wasn't always black cloth. At one time it was green. If I remember my history correctly,  it was the Fatimids who started the custom of using black cloth, a tradition that is continued on today by the Saudi government.

Comment: [Was the custom of covering Kaaba in black cloth adopted during the Fatimid era?](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/11086/3175)

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard and fast rule that only Black color is standard. its just like a Covering, in Black color. there is nothing much imporant about color. it can be any color, it doesnt matter

Comment: I was more interested in why a cloth at all?

Answer (score -2):

black is usually associated with the occult or the dead and heavy in symbolism. it is a representation. it is surprising that its chosen colour is black.  it used to be different colours. at various times it was red, green, white and yellow.  a family the abbasids chose the black colour and it has remained that colour since without change.  it also used to be rectangle in shape and has been changed into a cube.

Comment: many upsetting things to consider.  our world is heavy in symbolism and it is all around us.  the kaaba used to be a rectangle and now it is a cube, a black cube which represents the black cube of saturn.  saturn is associated with satan.  look it up.  muslims are made to walk around the kaaba 7 times.  google number 7 numerology.